# Mismatch on sign: 'unsigned short' passed as _Param when some signed type is required in call to 'swprintf'

Tags: visual-c++

Mismatch on sign: 'unsigned short' passed as _Param when some signed type is required in call to 'swprintf'.
    swprintf( buffer, L"%04d-%02d-%02d-%02d.%02d.%02d.%03d000",
                            sysTime.wYear, sysTime.wMonth, sysTime.wDay, 
                            sysTime.wHour, sysTime.wMinute, sysTime.wSecond, 
                            sysTime.wMilliseconds );

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Did the error message really say "some signed type"?

Comment: yes. here is the warning message again: "warning C6340: Mismatch on sign: 'unsigned short' passed as _Param_(7) when some signed type is required in call to 'swprintf'. "

Comment: The warning appears spurious. `unsigned short` would be promoted to `int` under default argument promotions, which matches `%d` format specifiers just fine. Your code looks good to me as written. But, if you want to make it happy, replace `%d` with `%u`

Comment: warning C6328: Size mismatch: 'unsigned short' passed as _Param_(6) when '32 bit operand' is required in call to 'swscanf_s'. This indicates a potential severe error. Buffer underrun or overrun can occur when when this is reported for scanf-like functions. This is the warning thats showing now..please help!

Answer (score 1):

The members of the `SYSTEMTIME` structure are of type `WORD`. [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The type `WORD` is a 16-bit unsigned integer (most likely `unsigned short`). [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

`swprintf`'s `"%d"` specifier requires an argument of type `int`.

It's a bit odd that your compiler is warning you about this. If `int` is wider than `short` (which is common but not guaranteed), then an argument of type `unsigned short`, when passed to a variadic function like `swprintf`, will be prompted to `int`. (If `int` and `short` are the same width, an `unsigned short` will be promoted to `unsigned int`.)

You can avoid the problem by ensuring that all your arguments are actually of type `int`:

```
swprintf( buffer, L"%04d-%02d-%02d-%02d.%02d.%02d.%03d000",
          (int)sysTime.wYear, (int)sysTime.wMonth, (int)sysTime.wDay,
          (int)sysTime.wHour, (int)sysTime.wMinute, (int)sysTime.wSecond,
          (int)sysTime.wMilliseconds );
```

For functions with a fixed number and types of parameters, arguments of arithmetic type (signed integer, unsigned integer, or floating-point) are implicitly converted to the correct type. For variadic functions like `printf` and `swprintf`, the declaration of the function doesn't provide this information (and the format string can even be a variable, leaving the compiler completely in the dark about what types are expected), and so you have to be much more careful to ensure that you're passing arguments of the correct type.

(The "some signed type" warning is very odd. *Some* warning is warranted, since passing an `unsigned short` with a `"%d"` format is not portable, but the promoted argument must be specifically of type `int`. Passing a `long` or `long long`, each of which is "some signed type", would be equally incorrect.)